# Closure examination causing unexpected Stack Overflow Error

Tags: groovy, closures, stack-overflow

I'm trying to use this code to better understand how `this`, `owner`, and `delegate` work in Groovy Closures:

```
class GroovyTest {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        examine() {
            println 'In first closure'
            println "class is ${getClass().name}"
            println "this is $this, super: ${this.getClass().getSuperclass().name}"
            println "owner is $owner, super: ${owner.getClass().getSuperclass().name}"
            println "delegate is $delegate, super: ${delegate.getClass().getSuperclass().name}"

            examine() {
                println 'In closure within the closure'
                println "class is ${getClass().name}"
                println "this is $this, super: ${this.getClass().getSuperclass().name}"
                println "owner is $owner, super: ${owner.getClass().getSuperclass().name}"
                println "delegate is $delegate, super: ${delegate.getClass().getSuperclass().name}"
            }
        }
    }

    static examine(closure) {
        closure()
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, it results in a Stack Overflow Error, however I am having difficulty figuring out what is causing the infinite recursion. I'm including part of the stack trace here:

```
Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at GroovyTest$_main_closure1.doCall(GroovyTest.groovy:10)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at GroovyTest$_main_closure1$_closure2.doCall(GroovyTest.groovy:14)
    at GroovyTest$_main_closure1$_closure2.doCall(GroovyTest.groovy)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at GroovyTest.examine(GroovyTest.groovy:21)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at GroovyTest$_main_closure1.doCall(GroovyTest.groovy:10)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at GroovyTest$_main_closure1$_closure2.doCall(GroovyTest.groovy:14)
    at GroovyTest$_main_closure1$_closure2.doCall(GroovyTest.groovy)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at GroovyTest.examine(GroovyTest.groovy:21)
```

It appears that the line `println "owner is $owner, super: ${owner.getClass().getSuperclass().name}"` is causing the infinite recursion.

Why is this code causing a Stack Overflow Error, and what can I do to fix it?

***Edit***: The following script, which also contains nested closures, works exactly as intended. The Stack Overflow Exception isn't being caused by the nested closures itself. It seems like it has something to do with the print statement.

```
def examiningClosure(closure) {
  closure()
}

examiningClosure() { 
  println "In First Closure:"
  println "class is " + getClass().name
  println "this is " + this + ", super:" + this.getClass().superclass.name
  println "owner is " + owner + ", super:" + owner.getClass().superclass.name
  println "delegate is " + delegate +
              ", super:" + delegate.getClass().superclass.name
  
  examiningClosure() { 
    println "In Closure within the First Closure:"
    println "class is " + getClass().name
    println "this is " + this + ", super:" + this.getClass().superclass.name
    println "owner is " + owner + ", super:" + owner.getClass().superclass.name
    println "delegate is " + delegate +
                ", super:" + delegate.getClass().superclass.name
  }  
}
```

Comment: You are calling `examine` from within the closure already executing within `examine` thus causing a recursion of infinite depth. That is more or less the definition of a `StackOverflowException`. If you remove the second call it should go away.

I.e. you run `examine` which calls `examine` which again calls `examine` which again calls `examine` ad infinitum.

Comment: @MatiasBjarland The first closure simply calls the second closure. Why should that necessarily result in a StackOverflowError? Nothing in this closure recourses. The first method call contains a closure which contains a second method call. The second, nested, method call doesn't itself contain the method call, so it should terminate with that.

Groovy allows nested closures. That's not what's causing the error. The stack trace indicates that the issue has something to do with the line this line in particular: `println "owner is $owner, super: ${owner.getClass().getSuperclass().name}"`

Comment: FYI... Your problematic scenario can be simplified a lot to make the issue easier to work with.  See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/d483a8f743947da50f3f84ed8149f592.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'll start by apologizing for not taking the time to look into this properly.

Will try to make up for it with an actual explanation.

Turns out that following code:

```
def c = {
  println "foo"
}

println "${c}"
```

somewhat unintuitively results in the closure being executed instead of just getting a string representation of it printed on std out:

```
─➤ groovy test.groovy
foo
```

So in the case of your example:

```
class GroovyTest {
    static void main(args) {
        examine { // closure 1
            examine { // closure 2
                println "${owner}"
            }
        }
    }

    static examine(closure) {
        closure()
    }
}
```

(parens after the `examine` method call can be omitted)

the `owner` of the innermost closure is the innermost closure itself. Calling the enclosing closure will result in the infinite recursion of self-calls and eventually a `StackOverflowException`.

You can fix this by for example instead do `println "${owner.getClass()}"` which prevents the implicit closure call.

I would have to say that the closure call from `"${closure}"` is quite unintuitive and not at all what I expected...after years and years of using groovy...but there it is.

Comment: Would this case from the docs be an example of what we're seeing here. or is this something else? https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_special_case_of_interpolating_closure_expressions